# Some iPhone/iPad photos do not appear on the map of iPhoto

Tags: iphone, ipad, photos.app, maps

It happens to me sometimes that using iPhone or iPad, I take pictures in open air environments, but later, when photos are exported to iPhoto, they do not appear on the Map. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add or correct wrong GPS-data to your photo with the app **iMetaPhoto**.

I had the same problem, I took 4 photos at the same location, but only the last photo was correctly geotagged. Wit iMetaPhoto you can take this correct GPS-data and save it to the wrong ones.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the device did not have a GPS fix at the time you took the picture.  If I really want a photo to have a location tag, I bring up the map application and wait for it to get a precise fix before taking the picture.  This can take up to a minute, so you have to plan ahead if you really want an accurate GPS tag.

Note that if you don't do that, the photo may still be tagged and that tag might be correct, or it might be completely wrong.  If the device has not moved much since it last ran a location aware app, or if the photo app has been running for a minute or two, then it may have enough of a fix to generate an accurate tag.  Or it might wrongly think it has enough of a fix and generate a completely incorrect tag.  Running the mapping program is just a way to improve the odds of an accurate tag.

Comment: you are mostly right, but the problem is, I do not have a data plan when I am with my iPad/iphone abroad. so i need to find a system that, not using wifi or 3g, checks or tries to get the current GPS coordinates before taking a photo. I will try with an offline maps application like some from openstreetmap

Comment: It does not need to be a map application: anything which requests precision location information will work.  I have an app called "Here I am" which simply displays the current lat/lon.  It may also work to just leave the Photo app running for a minute before you take a picture, its just hard to tell when it gets a location lock.

Answer (score 0):

The Map function requires that the photos be tagged with GPS co-ordinates, either these photos do not have any recorded in the metadata, or as is sometimes the case, GPS info is wrong.

Select a problematic photo in iPhoto and "Show Photo Info", the GPS co-ordinates appear under the Exposure tab as:

- GPS Latitude
- GPS Longitude
- GPS Altitude (not always present)